# Calculate the complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I have an algorithm here and it wants me to calculate the complexity:

```
for (i=1;i<n;i++)
  for (j=1;j<i*i;j++)
    if (j%i==0)
       for (k=0;k<j;k++)
          sum++;
```

First of all, I think that i have different complexities for best, average and worst case but I don't know how to find them. I have one though and I said that in the best case I will have the 2 fors and count as operation the 'if'. So i have a double sum (ΣΣ 1) with bounds being the values of i,j in the for loops. That's all i did.

Comment: In addition to our reference question covering this, you may want to search for questions about [tag:algorithm-analysis+loops].

Answer (score 0):

The number of times that the *if* is executed is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (i^2-1) = \Theta(n^3).
$$
The number of times that *sum* is incremented is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{\substack{1 \leq j < i^2 \\ i \mid j}} j =
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} ki = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i \binom{i}{2} = \Theta(n^4).
$$
Altogether, we get a running time of $\Theta(n^4)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is for all occasions? Isn't there separation of best, average, worst case?

Comment: The running time here only depends on $n$, so there is only one case, which is both the best case and the worst case, as well as the average case. These distinctions are only meaningful when the algorithm has other inputs, such as an array of length $n$.

Comment: Duhh there are many opinions. Some find it n^5. Anyway, thank you very much for your reply, you helped!

Comment: It's true that $O(n^5)$ is a trivial upper bound, but this upper bound can actually be improved to the tight bound $\Theta(n^4)$. Those who guess $n^5$ are ignoring the *if*.

Comment: Note that there are no "opinions". One opinion is true, and the others are false. That's the way it works in mathematics.

Comment: There's the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071692/big-o-analysis-for-this-for-loop . Look at the last answer. He finds n^5

Comment: I wouldn't trust stackoverflow on these matters. The average programmer isn't particularly good in math.

Comment: Ok my friend. I'll trust you. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You don't have to trust me. You can follow my (abbreviated) argument, and see for yourself. In math we don't trust authority, we verify proofs.

Comment: Yeah I don't "catch" it completely so... :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60086/discussion-between-georgio3-and-yuval-filmus).